# How to get errors in web console programatically

Tags: javascript, extension-methods

I am trying to get the web console errors and warning using Javascript.
Basically i am designing a browser plugin to get errors those have been logged in web console, without opening dev toolbar(F12).

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: u can still see the console.log() in a cmd-prompt or atom platformio-ide-plugin using "node 1.js"

Comment: u can try log4js

Answer (score -2):

You can try using try catch block in your javascript method

Comment: This is a mere hint, not an answer.

Comment: Actually it is a plugin, so basically i want access to console messages.Also i wont be having access to the JS code.